# SELECT en INSERT según parámetros

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statements

Buenas, tengo la tabla Inventario y Modelo, en Inventario tengo un desplegable que me muestra todos los modelos, lo que quiero hacer es que al yo elegir un modelo del desplegable e introduzca los demás datos de inventario inserte el id_modelo por el que están comunicadas las tablas que corresponde el modelo elegido en el desplegable, no sé si me explico correctamente, he intentado varias consultas insert con select pero ninguna me ha resultado útil.

Dejo las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo también parte del código que estaba intentado hacer.

```
    $nombre_producto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['nombre_producto']);
    $cantidad = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cantidad']);
    $precio = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['precio']);
    $modelo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['modelo']);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO inventario (nombre_producto, cantidad, precio)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sii", $nombre_producto, $cantidad, $precio);
    $stmt->execute();
}

/*
"INSERT INTO inventario (id_modelo, nombre_producto, cantidad, precio) 
 SELECT mod2.id_modelo, inv.nombre_producto, inv.cantidad, inv.precio 
 FROM inventario AS inv 
 JOIN modelos AS mod2 
 ON inv.id_modelo = mod2.id_modelo 
 WHERE inv.id_modelo = '?'
 AND 




"
*/
```

Gracias !!

Comment: Creo que la falta claridad a tu pregunta. Para poder entender mejor sería bueno que nos cuentes el **escenario**. Lo imagino de esta forma: estás en un formulario en el cual rellenas varios campos del tipo `input` y en dicho formulario tienes cargado un `select` para elegir un modelo, y además un botón **Insertar**. Rellenas tus inputs, seleccionas un modelo y le das click a insertar. Entonces quieres que tome todo lo que hay en el formulario y te lo inserte en una tabla de tu BD. ¿Es eso? Si es eso, es muy fácil: **se trata de cargar en tu form los modelos en un select** y tomar su id en PHP.

Comment: exacto, es eso, el caso es que necesitaría insertar también el id_modelo para que concuerde con el valor elegido en la etiqueta select, no ? porque si no ese registro no se va a rellenar ya que no es AI y en el listado de la tabla no va a aparecer el nombre del modelo para cada producto, no ?

Comment: La respuesta de @RobertoLeónOramas te da la pista de la solución. Tu select debe ser algo así más o menos: `<select name="modelo">
   <option value="1">modelo1</option>
   <option value="2">modelo2</option>
   <option value="3">modelo3</option>
</select>` luego lo obtienes por `$_POST['modelo']` y lo incluyes en la cadena `INSERT INTO inventario (id_modelo,...)` con su respectivo placeholder (?), claro... y en el `bind_param(...)` por supuesto. Por cierto, usa `$_POST[...]` en lugar de `$_REQUEST[...]`

Comment: También, si el escenario es un formulario donde introduces tus datos, no tienes que hacer `SELECT...` de tus modelos **cada vez** que intentas insertar, lo que debes hacer es **tener cargados tus modelos en el formulario** para que el usuario pueda seleccionar el modelo adecuado, de ese modo ganas en rendimiento y no molestas tanto a la BD pidiéndole datos que podrías tener cargados mientras el formulario esté abierto.

Comment: El caso es que los modelos los introduzco dinámicamente en una sección que tengo para ellos por lo que los option los recorro con un bucle while de toda la tabla modelos

Comment: Ya, pero eso no es problema. Tienes tu formulario con campos de texto y en él un combobox o select con los modelos que ya están cargados. Seleccionas un modelo una vez has llenado los demás campos y pulsas en  insertar. Pero el INSERT tiene que tener entre los campos que quieres insertar el `id_modelo` que has tomado del combobox. Creo que hay algo del enfoque del formulario y de su funcionamiento que no has entendido bien y de ahí tu dificultad. ¿O es que los modelos cambian, es decir, tienes que elegir grupos de modelos o modelos diferentes según varios casos?

Comment: Claro, yo tengo una sección totalmente a parte donde puedo crear modelos así como modificarlos o borrarlos, por eso no los tengo cargados, y luego recorro en ese select todos los modelos de la tabla modelos para poder asignarle el quiera a un producto

Comment: Eso **tampoco** es problema. Puedes tener en el mismo archivo tu sección modelos y si agregas alguno **actualizar el select o combobox de modelos a través de Ajax** (de ese modo no tienes que volver a cargar la página) y tienes siempre actualizada tu lista de modelos para poder elegir el que necesites a la hora de insertar en la tabla `inventario`.

Comment: Así lo he hecho al final A. Cedano, le he añadido ajax y he encontrado una solución a los insert y me los muestra perfectamente, te agradezco mucho tu atención y respuesta. Gracias ! :D

Comment: Me alegro :) Para que la pregunta no quede abierta, si @RobertoLeónOramas está de acuerdo puede añadir lo de Ajax a su respuesta y la puedes marcar como solución. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos.

Mira en [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php); con esa instrucción obtienes el más reciente elementos (que sea de autoincremento) que fue creado; desde luego debes considerar que debe ser la instrucción inmediata seguida del insert sin haber cerrado la conexión con que fue realizada.

De esa forma obtiene el valor del ID generado para usarlo en tu siguiente consulta que la requieres.

## ACTUALIZACION

Entendi de primer momento que querias obtener un ID recien ingresado; mira tu código en el `INSERT` estas pasando solo 3 parámetros al mismo; no estas incluyendo `$modelo`; seguro (pienso más bien) que ese corresponde al `SELECT` que mencionas y no esta como parte del **prepare** ni **bind_param** del `INSERT`.

```
$nombre_producto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['nombre_producto']);
$cantidad = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cantidad']);
$precio = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['precio']);
$modelo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['modelo']); // Este no lo estas incluyendo

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO inventario (id_modelo, nombre_producto, cantidad, precio)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: El caso es que en ningún momento creo un modelo, estos ya están creados y se eligen a través de una etiqueta select de HTML. Para utilizar el insert_id debería hacer primero un select que me lo saque y luego el insert con el resultado de ese select, cosa que no descarto hacer pero si puedo hacerlo todo en una sola consulta mucho mejor. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Lo del más reciente elemento no es mucho de fiar, pues según el contexto y la base de datos, no siempre devuelve los valores reales. En algunos contextos, por ejemplo, si hay un fallo en la consulta, podría devolver cero `0` como valor. Por otra parte, si la BD es usada por varias personas a la vez, contar con el último insertado es aún más problemático.

Comment: Como dice A. Cedano la base de datos va a ser utilizada por varias personas al mismo tiempo por lo que entonces no me conviene utilizar insert_id. Sobre lo de tu actualización he hecho esto: http://i.imgur.com/G8l3CZM.jpg pero me sigue sin insertar nada de nada, y el select está bien pues si sustituyo $modelo por un valor me saca el id de este.

Comment: @Cifu no se como estas llenado tu SELECT; considero lo correcto debia ser algo como <select id="modelo" name="modelo"> **<option value="aqui el id_modelo">** *aqui la marca* **</opcion>** [tantos option como necesites] </select>